# C# / If, If else with count

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to create an "if/else if statement" where the "else if" activates after the first "if" activates and counted up in addition to being multi-conditioned. The User would input the first "look" and get a "0" in response, and then after entering the second "look", they'll get a 1.

Here's the code:

```
string comAns = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
int count = 0;

if (comAns == "LOOK" && count == 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("0");
    count = 1;

} else if (comAns == "LOOK" && count == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");

}
debug();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: If the code goes into the `if` part, it will never go into the `else if` part, no matter if you set you set `count=1`. In an `if / else if  / else` statement, only one block will ever be executed. Remove the `else` to get a separate if-statement and to execute the second block as well.

Comment: *"and then after entering the second "look""* - The code shown only prompts for input once.  Did you mean to write a loop somewhere?

Comment: _where the "else if" activates after the first "if" activates_  That's completely against the purpose of what `else` is designed to achieve.  `else` is a [fork in the road](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Entroncamento_do_Transpraia.JPG), where you follow one path of execution or the other but not both.  If that doesn't suit your needs, then don't use `else`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't want the `else` at all, you want something like this:

```
    string comAns = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();  // bad, use proper case-insensitive equality
    int count = 0;

    if (comAns == "LOOK" && count == 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("0");
        count = 1;
    } 

    if (comAns == "LOOK" && count == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this isn't the solution I was looking for, if I do it like that the console would look like something like that:
     look
     0
    1
but I need it like that:
    look
    0
   look
   1

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Wambur please re-read your own question - there is no indication that you need to repeatedly ask for the input written in the question.